# How to use elementFromPoint(x,y).click() on an object or iframe to simulate a click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm now a bit stuck in terms of simulating a user click on an object which redirects to another url.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VNC Interface</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="thisAddress">
        </div>
        <object id="target" type="text/html" data="" width="850px" height="820px" style="overflow:auto">
        </object>
    </div>

<script>


    document.getElementById('target').data = 'http://someurl.com';
    
     document.body.addEventListener('pointerdown', function(e) {
    
         
         document.elementFromPoint(e.x, e.y).click();
         console.log("down!");
         console.log(e);
     });


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The above code was trying to simulate a user clicking on a pointerdown event. The reason I'm doing this is that this index.html page is running not on a conventional browser but an ar toolbox. I have to register the click via something like `document.elementFromPoint(x,y).click()`. But I realize this method is probably problematic since the document.elementFromPoint(x,y) would be the `<object id="target">`, rather than the specific button I'm looking for. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: And I also have tried to use iframe instead of an object, no luck

Comment: I think this question can be better summarised as how to use `elementFromPoint()` from the specific `object` or `iframe`, rather than the base html document.

Comment: If you want to run an event from a specific element, just add the event listener to that element instead of the document: `document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('pointerdown', function(e) { if (e.target) { e.target.elementFromPoint(e.x, e.y).click(); } });` Haven't actually tested this, but it's the first idea that comes to mind.

Comment: I'm afraid this cannot be done. Because this is not a conventional browser. It's an ar app that runs a html page as a floating ar screen. The app is running on webview on ios devices, so there will be a controller page and an ar html page. If I use document.getElementById('target') there will be nothing because the `target` is not on the controller webview page, the `target` is on the ar html page.

Comment: You can understand it it as a browser within a browser